# How to avoid echo area conflict between gnus and emacs-pinentry?

Tags: minibuffer, gnus, echo-area

I use GNU Pass for my password manager, emacs-pinentry for my GPG pinentry, and Gnus as my mail reader. This has created a problem for me when Gnus and emacs-pinentry both need to use the echo area/minibuffer.

1. Start Gnus. It automatically starts pulling mail, echoing a message saying it is doing so.
2. It needs my mail password, so it calls Pass. (I have `:password (string-trim (shell-command-to-string "pass my-email"))` in the mail source config.)
3. Pass needs my GPG password to decrypt and fetch my mail password.
4. GPG calls emacs-pinentry to get that password...except it can't display the prompt in the minibuffer, because Gnus is already echoing a message to it.
5. Hang until I press `C-g` to cancel it, at which point I see a pinentry-gtk window appear and can enter my password into *that*.

It seems like to resolve this, I'll either need to prevent Gnus from using the echo area until it has my password, or have emacs-pinentry prompt me somewhere other than the minibuffer. Or maybe there's a third way that I'm not seeing, or I'm wrong about what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who happens to have this same issue in the future, the best solution I found is to just not configure an email password at all; the `:password` field turns out to be optional. It will just prompt for the password, at which point you can fetch and paste in your password like normal. (It also works with `password-store-copy`, by the way.)